# How to get bundle in form alter?

Tags: 8, forms

I want bundle in `hook_form_alter`. In Drupal7 we can get all these in hook_form_alter.

I tried like this in D7:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $bundle_type = $form['#bundle'];
}
```

Here I am getting bundle in D7.
Whereas in D8 I am not getting any bundle like article/page/tags etc.,

Comment: So you want the node bundle basically?

Comment: not only node bundle, i need that form bundle like article(node), tags(taxonomy, etc) in hook_form_alter().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the final solution:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;

$bundle = FALSE;
$form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
if ($form_object instanceof ContentEntityForm) {
  $bundle = $form_object->getEntity()->bundle();
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, you should check if $form_object is an EntityFormInterface object. This will result in a fatal error on any other form like login, search and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer altough your answer was correct, but giving some fatal error like **Berdir** said.
This works fine form me and no fatal errors.
 `$bundle = FALSE;   
  if ($form_object = $form_state->getFormObject()) {
    if ($form_object instanceof Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm) {
      $bundle = $form_object->getEntity()->bundle();
    }
    elseif ($form_object instanceof Drupal\field_ui\Form\FieldConfigEditForm) {
      $bundle = $form_object->getEntity()->bundle();
    }
  }`

Comment: I will edit right now! Thank you for the correction!